CORS Policy Issue with specific browser
Issue: origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Note: below code working last few years but suddenly stop working with Chrome Browser. FrontEnd developed in Angular and backend with Spring Boot Application.
Code:
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
        response.setHeader("Access-control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
            try {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}


We tried below solution but still we get the issue.
CORS not working on Chrome
Ionic - blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
Spring Boot CORS filter - CORS preflight channel did not succeed

Seems quite unlikely that something that "was working for the last few years" suddenly stopped working without any change being done. Have you had any recent updates to your backend? Did you inspect the calls your browser complained about with the developer tools? Were they infact missing the CORS headers? To be honest, the most probable causesfor me seems to be that there was a change in the backend that stopped the above code from being executed. Or there was a change in the frontend that requests a new endpoint which doesn't trigger the above code ...

I've never used spring-boot so I cannot say if the above code is correct, but it seems to be fine. The only strange thing that comes to my eye, is that your are setting a SC_OK status code before you completed your chain. But that might be OK with the framework you are using ...

Change the CorsMapping from registry.addMapping("/*") to registry.addMapping("/**") in addCorsMappings method
For More Information
Link
this might help you

@derpircher There is no change in frontend and backend code for this. As problem stats this code is only not working in chrome but working in edge browser.

it's working with Edge perfectly but problem with Chrome and other browser.
